# VBA-Macro efficiency with Bloomberg Data History

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

I'm very new to VBA. I wrote this code and it works, but it takes ages to run through and I get the feeling that its getting slower and slower the longer it has been running.

Is there a way I can make things like this more efficient? Would be awesome if anyone out there had some advise for me here.

```
Sub Sheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

Dim Data As String
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As String


For i = 2 To 255

Sheetname = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 1).Value
Worksheets.Add.Name = Sheetname
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

x = 1

For k = 2 To 876
Data = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, k).Value
y = Cells(1, x).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
BloomB = "=BDH(" & y & ",""TURNOVER"",""8/1/2011"",""4/30/2016"",""Dir=V"",""Dts=S"",""Sort=A"",""Quote=C"",""QtTyp=Y"",""Days=T"",""Per=cd"",""DtFmt=D"",""UseDPDF=Y"")"
Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, x) = Data
Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(2, x) = BloomB
x = x + 2
Next k

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Next i

ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For benefit of non-Bloomberg users, BDH() is a Bloomberg add-in function, short for Bloomberg Data History

Comment: Someone told me that if I added this timer after every runthrough it would help excel not to slow down. Is that a myth then?

Comment: @Yarza - it's a lie.

Comment: @Yarza: seems very curious that such an obvious slowdown has been added, I wonder if Bloomberg don't like their servers being hit so intensely.  So I wonder if it might very well be deliberate.

Comment: it looks like you are filling your worksheets with a huge amount of formulas.  If this is historic data then it doesn't change, i.e. it is static.  So why have formulas to recalculate.  Why not hard code the results?

Comment: @S Meaden: The way I understand it I need the formula so it downloads the data I need over the bloomberg add-in. How could I hard code that?

Comment: @Yarza: I added some code to an answer that will hard-coded results to the worksheet.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))`. Or put `Next i` above it like this:

```
Next i
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
```

You would gain about 43 minutes.

If you still like the idea of waiting, do it a bit more sophisticated, like this:

```
If i Mod 50 = 0 Then Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Next i
```

Thus, it would wait on every 50th iteration.

Answer (score 0):

does it not all translate to being along the lines of A2 being `=offset(Input!B1,row(),0)` and B2 being `=BDH(ADDRESS(ROW(),1,4),""TURNOVER.....` as formula just being filled down?

Comment: to be honest, I dont fully understand what you mean. would be really nice if you could explain that to me.

Comment: What you are doing constructing the formula, is just replacing row numbers and addresses, so you can use the formula `row()` and the formula `address` instead, add 1 row, fill down, then continue the loop of `i` Let excel's fill down do your loop `For k = 2 To 876`  Run one loop of I and look at the result, the formula can be done by cell references being filled down.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comments about hard-coding.  Here is some code to help not call static data functions repeatedly

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)

    rng.Formula = "=SIN(PI()/4)"  '* a formula is in fact constant

    '* in some instances Evaluate will suffice
    Dim vHardcodedFormulaResult As Variant
    vHardcodedFormulaResult = Application.Evaluate("SIN(PI()/4)")

    rng.Offset(1, 0).Value2 = vHardcodedFormulaResult

    '* in other cases Application.Run will be needed and also multi-cell return results

    Dim vHardcodedFormulaResult2 As Variant
    vHardcodedFormulaResult2 = Application.Run("FakeBDH", "Citi", "FakeParam")

    Dim lIndex As Long
    lIndex = 0
    Dim vLoop As Variant
    For Each vLoop In vHardcodedFormulaResult2

        rng.Offset(2, lIndex) = vLoop
        lIndex = lIndex + 1
    Next vLoop


End Sub


Function FakeBDH(ByVal sKey As String, ByVal vParam1) As Variant
    FakeBDH = Array(2015, 45000)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I just add those codelines to my code? Or what should I do with them? Please forgive me if it is a stupid question.

Comment: @Yarza: I can't rewrite your code as I do not have Bloomberg, if you have Bloomberg I presume you an IT department, they ought to be able to help if you give them the above sample code.

Comment: @S Meaden: Actually I'm just a university kid that did some macros before and tries to help a friend with her PhD thesis. So sadly, there is no IT departement to back me up here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what are you trying to do, exactly?  Do you want time series data for equities?  Is so, try the link below.

http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/

[image]